# CSS styling -- span with different font size inside of div

Tags: html, css

I have a piece of code that compares the same line across multiple poems.  It works fine, except for when the initial letter of the line appears in the manuscript original as a large capital, like this:

[image]

As you can see, when that happens the comparison gets all wonky.  As far as I can tell, this is because the W is a `span` encapsulated inside of a `div`:

```
<div class="comparison" id="EETS.QD.1" style="display: block;">
    <div class="compare_item" style="margin-left: 25px;">London, British Library Harley 2251: 
        <a style="text-decoration:none; color:#D5D5E5;" href="Quis_Dabit/British_Library_Harley_2251/British_Library_Harley_2251_f42v.html">
            <span class="capital_2_blue">W</span>
         ho shal gyve · vnto my hede a welle 
        </a>
   </div>
</div>
```

with the style attributes generated via javascript because the comparison is generated onClick. The CSS I use to style both the divs and the span is as follows:

```
div.comparison { 
    display: block;
    height: auto; 
    width: 755px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin-left: auto; 
    background-color: #454595; 
    border-width: 1px; 
    font-size: 12pt; 
    color: #EFFFFF; 
    display: none;
} 

span.capital_2_blue{
    float: left;
    color: blue;
    font-size: 60pt;
    line-height: 12pt;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```

My question is this: how can I display each of the lines so that any oversized letters appear at the beginning of the actual line of text, as expected?  This is what I'm shooting for:

[image]

I've been able to achieve it, sort of, by adding `display:contents` to the styling for my `span`, but that makes the W extend outside of the generated `div` on the page:

[image]

How would I go about styling these elements to achieve the look I'm hoping for, with the initials staying the height they're displayed in the text proper but not wrapping as they are currently?  And how do I make sure the `span` plays nicely with its surrounding `div`?  Thank you.

Comment: i'm not quite sure what is expected result. Maybe you should remove `float:left` and add `display:inline-block` to `span.capital_2_blue`.

Comment: That does it.  It means I have to add more css to differentiate this from where it's used elsewhere, but it achieves what I asked.  If you want to write it up as a formal answer I'll be happy to vote for it.Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove `float:left` and add `display:inline-block` to `span.capital_2_blue`.

That is because floated content removed from normal flow and other content will wrap around it.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float